# Save activity state Android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How could i save the activity state and values after closing application and when i open it again it have the values of radio button and spinner and edit text

in android studio in kotlin or in java

Answer (score 1):

You could save your data in SQLite database before closing your application and then retrieving again when the activity is started. Checkout this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) on how to use Room to save data. I also recommend you to read about other types of storage [in this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

Comment: could you give me an example please ??

Comment: try coding this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0), it will teach you the basics of room.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharedPreferences.

SharedPreferences can be used as some sort of cache/cookie which will be useful when the user's detail/action is to be remembered when he comes back to use the application.

Android provides many ways of storing data of an application. One of this way is called Shared Preferences. Shared Preferences allow you to save and retrieve data in the form of key,value pair.